# Google Maps V3 API - Get markers in a range

Tags: codeigniter, maps

I`m using Google Maps V3 API Codeigniter Library and I`m trying to return all the markers in a determined range, there is a way to do this? Like, Finding places closer to my geolocation.

Thank you!